# What algorithm/encryption type does Gmail use for security?

Tags: encryption, passwords, email, file-encryption, google

In the wake of the recent database hacks, i.e. Sony, Gawker, etc.. where the hackers have access to the hashed usernames and passwords, i've been more keen in paying attention to the sites and services i regularly use, and am paying more attention to how my data is stored. I know that Gawker used DES, i believe, to encrypt their info, which is not as effective as a newer method such as AES.

So do we know what encryption type Google uses or how many rounds of salt they use for their services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: Google have not published any details of the internal workings of their sign-on mechanisms.

Comment: would google docs storage security be on par with that of say Dropbox?

Comment: @zm15 - All of Google's services uses the same authentication system.  There is nothing special about dropbox's authentication system.